# Eloquent Query for "BelongsToMany" Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

When I want to query for all states a specific dispatch ticket in my database, I would do it like this:

```
public function test() {
    $dispatches = Dispatch::where('dispatch_reference', '=', 'dis_548k14s4glnhv5')->get();
    foreach($dispatches->states as $state) {
        var_dump($state);
    }
}
```

But this throws an error message, that `states` is not being recognized. The models I created are:

**Dispatch**

```
class Dispatch extends Model {

    use EventGenerator;

    protected $table = 'dispatches';
    protected $fillable = ['dispatch_reference', 'incident_reference', 'state'];
    public $timestamps = true;

    // Since the FK exists in this table, the belongsTo() method is used to state that the dispatch model is related to an address.
    // Dispatch __belongs_to__ Incident
    public function incident() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Classes\Incident');
    }

    // Dispatch __belongs_to_many__ State
    public function states() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Classes\DispatchState')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function attachDispatchState($id) {
        $this->states()->attach($id);
        $this->touch();
    }

    // set fields on the eloquent object and save to database
    // raise event that the incident was created.
    public function createDispatch($command) {

        // Get BodyContent from POST Request
        $this->dispatchReference = $command->dispatchReference;
        $this->incidentReference = $command->incidentReference;

        // Create new Dispatch
        $dispatch = Dispatch::create(array(
            'dispatch_reference' => $this->dispatchReference,
            'incident_reference' => $this->incidentReference
        ));
        $dispatchState = DispatchState::where('state', '=', 'processing')->first();
        $dispatch->attachDispatchState($dispatchState->id);

        return $this;
    }
```

**Dispatch State**

```
class DispatchState extends Model {

    use EventGenerator;

    // Define Table Setup with fillabe fields
    protected $table = 'dispatch_states';

    // Fillable fields in database
    protected $fillable = ['state'];

    // include timestamps
    public $timestamps = true;

    // Status __belongs_to_many__ Dispatches
    public function dispatches() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Classes\Dispatch');
    }
}
```

I would expect to see all the different states attached to one dispatch as i am using a pivot table that works fine so far. I just cannot query the results. Do I have an error in my models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're calling **get()** you're getting a collection of **Dispatch** object. If you expect to only get a single object (e.g. when dispatch reference is unique), call **first()** instead of **get()**:

```
$dispatch = Dispatch::where('dispatch_reference', '=', 'dis_548k14s4glnhv5')->first();
```

If, however, dispatch reference is not unique, you'll need to first iterate through collection of **dispatches** and then through their related states:

```
$dispatches = Dispatch::where('dispatch_reference', '=', 'dis_548k14s4glnhv5')->get();
foreach($dispatches as $dispatch) {
  foreach ($dispatch->states as $state) {
    var_dump($state);
  }
}
```

Comment: great!! I have timestamps attached to the pivot table. How can I then get the latest entry added to the pivot table? when I call a request i want to see the state that has been added to this request the latest

Comment: $latestState = $dispatch->states()->orderBy('pivot_created_at', 'desc')->first();

Comment: so I woud put that line into the first foreach loop?

Comment: I'm not sure what you need. If you want to get the latest state for each dispatch you can do that instead of iterating through $dispatch->states

Comment: Well I would always have a unique id available. so I would do the first solution and with the result added to the var $dispatch I could call the latest state by your functions provide?